# what does it mean

Tags: bitcoin-cash

In order to receive funds right now and not report on receipt in the supervisory authority , it is necessary to make a transfer to the cadastre of gratuitous rewards. This procedure is mandatory to receive the entire amount of payment.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? What is this about?

Comment: Sounds like a scam.